# How expensive is OpenFileMapping? (Memory Mapped File)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, ipc, memory-mapped-files

I'm using MMF as a way to share memory between multiple processes.

In my app, I have a process that creates a file mapping object that writes a bool value and other processes access(read) that value.

```
// First Process (Server)
// main.cpp
BOOL *pbVal;
HANDLE hFile = CreateFileMappingW(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 4, L"Global\\Test123");
if (hFile)
{
    pbVal = (BOOL *) MapViewOfFile(hFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0);
    if (pbVal)
    {
        Logger.LogPrint(_T("Mapped Memory."));
        *pbVal = TRUE;
        UnmapViewOfFile(pbVal);
    }
}
...
...
//closes the handle after use
```

```
// Other Processes (Clients)
// main.cpp
BOOL *pBool;
HANDLE hMapFile = OpenFileMappingW(FILE_MAP_READ, FALSE, L"Global\\Test123");
if (hMapFile)
{
    pBool = (BOOL*) MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_READ, 0 ,0, 4);
    if (pBool)
    {
        if (*pBool)
        {
            // Do Something
        }
        UnMapViewOfFile(pBool);
    }
}
CloseHandle(hMapFile);
```

I've skimmed through MSDN article [Managing Memory-Mapped Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms810613(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and some other articles and I understood MMF performs better than traditional file I/O in most cases. But, I want to know about the cost of MMF when it is used as a mean of IPC.

Because the fact that this method still involves I/O, I'm worried if accessing the shared memory consistently would harm the performance of my app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a case of premature optimization to me, if it's good enough for whatever you are doing then don't worry about it. Although I would probably do this via a DLL load-time linked with both executibles that hosts a shared memory segment. Simply because while it would have all the same code steps the OS would take care of the actual mechanics.

Comment: @Soronel Correct me if I'm wrong. Are you saying make one exe and one dll (that is loaded on every client) to implement MMF? Wouldn't it be the same?

Comment: *"Because the fact that this method still involves I/O, I'm worried if accessing the shared memory consistently would harm the performance of my app. "*



I wouldn't say this is I/O in the traditional sense, as it is not looking up a file in a HDD, or waiting for user interaction. In any case it's difficult to say if it would harm performance of your code, because you aren't comparing it to anything else.

Comment: Your other options seems to be to use something like a pipe, or a tcp connection to transfer the boolean. Which honestly seems better (and safer) to me because dealing with construction and destruction (and dereferencing) of shared memory to transfer a bool seems like overkill especially when it seems like you already have a server-client architecture in mind.

Comment: The cost of OpenFileMapping should be insignificant, assuming you open it just once and reuse the mapping rather than constantly opening and closing (which can get expensive). Once the map has been opened and mapped, it's just regular memory and is as fast as regular memory.

Comment: @Roy2511 I guess I'm comparing this method with other methods like piping or events. And you're right, I'm trying to wage between the cost of construction and destruction in MMF and making another thread in each process to listen.

Comment: @RaymondChen Okay, I see. My app does constantly open and close the mapping object, because it does not know when to check the shared memory (when the other app changes ``pBool``. Would you rather suggest to make another thread in the app to detect the changes?

Comment: You're not memory-mapping a file, so this is not I/O -- not anymore than how all physical memory is backed by the system paging file(s). You only need to map the Section object (file mapping) once. Assign the mapped address to a static variable and close the handle. The Section object is just required to setup references to the prototype page-table entries (software PTEs), which the memory manager uses as the true state of shared pages in order to make process hardware PTEs valid, as shared pages transition in and out of the working set of a process.

Comment: I hope you've paid attention to the fact that naming a Section object in the global namespace requires SeCreateGlobalPrivilege to be present and enabled, unless the caller is running in session 0 (services). Typically only administrators have this privilege. It's default enabled, but your code shouldn't rely on that. So if you're not running in session 0, try to enable SeCreateGlobalPrivilege and handle failure as required by your application.

Comment: "It does not know when to check the shared memory." If it doesn't know when to check the shared memory, how does it know when to call OpenFileMapping? Or are you saying that the code polls the variable? You can cache the handle in a state object, and have the caller use the state object. The state object opens the file mapping on first call and caches it for subsequent calls. It closes the handle on destruction. Other IPC methods also have state (pipe handle, TCP connection) so this problem is not unique to shared memory.

Comment: Thanks for helpful insights. I'm going to redesign my app so that I won't have to perform meaningless mapping sequences.